# How to fix problem installing tensorflow 1.5?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kaggle

I am working in Kaggle's notebook on an image segmentation problem. So far I did not have a problem installing TensorFlow 1.5 and Keras 2.1.5 so I can work with the Mask R-CNN model. But now I am getting this error: [image]

I would appreciate the help. I just don't understand how to fix it.

I install Tensorflow and Keras as I have always done:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.5 
!pip install keras==2.1.5

import tensorflow
import keras
```

Until yesterday it worked!

Comment: How do you install it? Also, please don't paste images, but copy the error message in a code block.

Comment: I edited my question and added the way I install tensorflow and keras.

Answer (score 0):

Check Settings in your Kaggle notebook. Internet must be set to - On.